# Как использовать разные шаблоны для vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router

На сайте имеются страницы с контентом и страницы входа и регистрации. Так вот для контента используется некая статичная часть с шапкой, футером и меню, а вот на вход и регистрацию, нужна другая статичная часть. Как с помощью vue-router это сделать?

[image: Код роутера]

[image: Точка входа]

Можно что то прописать в самом компоненте, что бы он использовал другой шаблон? Если нет, то как это сделать вообще?

Comment: вставьте пожалуйста в вопрос сам код, картинка не подходит так как её не индексируют поисковики

Comment: В App сделайте 2 варианта разметки и с помощью v-if v-else ставьте нужную. Проверяйте текущий роутер. если это '/auth' или '/reg' отдавайте первый если любой другой тогда второй. Или другой вариант сделать App нейтральным, создать 2 компонента,  с нужной версткой. а в них вложить все остальные как children.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем App.js можно использовать компонент-обертку или такую конструкцию:

```js
<component :is="routeListener"></component>

Импортируете ваши LayoutContent и LayoutAuth

components: {
  LayoutContent,
  LayoutAuth
}, 
computed: {
  routeListener () {
   // тут проверку по пути делаете
   if (this.$router.path === '/reg' || this.$router.path === '/auth')
     return 'layout-auth'
   else return 'layout-content'
 }
}
```